# Property "Raycast target" does not work in animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, animation, canvas, raycasting

**TL;DR** - Property "Raycast target" (from Image in Canvas) is successfully animated but has no real effect (passes events through itself when it should not).

---

I have Image in Canvas that I am animating. In animation I change "Raycast target" property so I can interact with buttons behind after the animation ends.

Propery changes in inspector, but has no effect - I can press buttons behind when animation hasn't finished yet and "Raycast target" is "True".

When I do not use animation and change propery directly through script - everything works as expected.

What am I missing?

My Scene:

```
Canvas
     |-Buttons
     |-Image (Foreground, Animated)
```

My animated Image:

[image]

My Animation:

[image]

Note: "Write Defaults" in animator does not affect anything.

Unity 2020.3.8.f1 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found solution, so I fixed problem through script. It checks animator state and manually changes property. In my case I have "Idle" state that is active when animation is not playing.

```
public class RaycastTargetFix : StateMachineBehaviour
{
    public string interactableState = "Idle";

    public override void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        var image = animator.GetComponent<Image>();
        if (image) image.raycastTarget = !stateInfo.IsName(interactableState);
    }
}
```

Script needs to be added to animator:

[image]

Of course raycastTarget property should not be animated, otherwise it cannot be changed through script.

Answer (score 0):

I think raycastTarget just enables Unity to consider this object for raycasting events. Turning it on or off may not make any difference to the elements behind it. I am not sure of it without testing but they have stated a single line for the raycastTarget property in the [Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic-raycastTarget.html) which does not help too much about this case.

I am sure that there is a blockRaycasts property on **CanvasGroup** component in Unity. Add this component to the object and it should block the elements behind it if it has a graphic (Image or something) attached to it.

Comment: I will quote my post `When I do not use animation and change propery directly through script - everything works as expected.`. Unfortunately blockRaycasts in CanvasGroup doesn't work in animation either.